# Allocate Space for object

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to load 2.5 million in my database  in sql server 2008 but i keep on getting the below error.

Additional information: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.DwH_Staging_Table' in database 'TestDB2' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

How to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried the suggestions in the error?

Comment: The message tells you very much about the problem (how much more explicit could it be?!) and inputting it into a search engine surely turns up the solution. -1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be simply resovled by following the advice in the errormessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hard drive section is full. You need more space to do that query. Try shrink database/files to free-up some space temporary:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189080(v=sql.105).aspx